# Is it safe to use static methods in a Play model

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

In Play 2.0m I have a static method in my model to wrap searching the DB:

```
public static User findUserByEmail(String email) {
    Finder<String, User> find = new Finder<String, User>(String.class, User.class);
    return find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
}
```

Is this threadsafe? I saw [How Playframework 1.x static method works in a thread safe way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110757/how-playframework-1-x-static-method-works-in-a-thread-safe-way) but I don't know if that applies to the models too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is thread-safe since you're only reading from the DB.
(and even if you were writing, I'm sure your DB can handle concurrent writes)

Comment: Isn't it possible (unlikely) that my "find" variable gets overridden by another thread?

Comment: No, because local variables are specific to a thread.  
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535237/local-variable-in-static-method-and-thread-safety